# Countdown timer onTick method not working

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a CountDown timer that fetches the value of a numberPicker. The text of my countdown timer will change to the value of the number picker, but when I hit the start button the value of the Countdown timer text view changes to a different number. So my question is how can I edit my code such that when I hit start it starts counting down the value of the textView. Here is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
NumberPicker noPickerHours;
NumberPicker noPickerMinutes;
TextView textViewTime;
Button button;
CounterClass timer;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    noPickerMinutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    noPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(59);
    noPickerMinutes.setMinValue(0);
    noPickerHours = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    noPickerHours.setMaxValue(24);
    noPickerHours.setMinValue(0);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 60), 1000);
            long millis = (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    });



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}




public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) * 60));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }


}}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Could someone just comment there thoughts on it. Anything will help

Comment: in your onValueChange you are setting your countdown timer with (newVal * 60 * 60) and then you are setting the textview with the long milis (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000), so the difference is * 1000 compared to what you initialized your countdown timer

Comment: ill put it up as an answer

Comment: Except it doesn't work when I make it more than 3 hours why is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your onValueChange() you are setting your countdown timer with (newVal * 60 * 60)

```
timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 60), 1000);
```

and then you are setting the textview with the long milis (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000)

```
long millis = (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

so the difference is * 1000 compared to what you initialized your countdown timer

Comment: This works, but when set the value of my numberPicker more that two hours it stops working.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out what was wrong. I just took out the * 60 * 1000 in my onTick String hms

Comment: ok, glad you got it, I was looking all around trying to think what was going on haha